# Designing indices to have paging with filters and random page jump Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash

I just want to have an expert opinion about my use case and the way I am planning to use indices to see if there is no problem in my approach or if there are any better ways to achieve it. Since I am new to ES, your opinions would really help me. We are storing data in couchdb in different databases based for each type of data.

I have database that serves as a link between 2 databases. For example, database A has 'floor' data, database B that links floor to items and then separate database for each item that a floor can have (e.g., card reader, camera etc).
We need to search for items that are linked to a floor and get them with filtering and paging. (Right now my links database has only ids and type but I am also planning to save name for each type as well in links db so that I can have filtering while I can do paging).

The way I want to achieve filtering and paging in my datastore is, I'll just have indices for each db. So based on floor, i'll get all its linked items for a type and 'search filter' (from index of links db) that would give me a page of certain items, i'll then use ids from that result to get those full objects (from index of) db of that item type.

Please let me know if there is any better approach in handling that, like e.g., if I can create one index for my floor and links and item databases and is it possible to do that through logstash couchdb plugin.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup does not sound wrong, but there are alternatives. You can use nested objects or parent-child relationships for an easier setup. Both approaches have their advantages. It all depends on the type of queries that you would like to do, and the amount of items that are related.

I would start by reading he next section of the definitive guide, that should give you a good start.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/modeling-your-data.html?q=model